# Deleting cell value using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my database table called 'AssignedExercises':

[image]

I'm trying to delete this value:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

This is my code...

```
var b = db.AssignedExercises.Where(m => m.Data_UserID.Equals(3)).FirstOrDefault();
db.AssignedExercises.Remove(b);
db.SaveChanges();
```

but it deletes a whole row. How should I change it?

Thanks!

Comment: `b.Monday = null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly removing the ***row***, which is represented by the ***entity object***.  ***Columns*** on the other hand are represented by ***properties*** on the object.  As a result, you need to update the property on the object itself.  Also, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` directly...the `Where()` is redundant.

```
var b = db.AssignedExercises.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Data_UserID.Equals(3));
if (b != null)
    b.Monday = null;    

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to clear out the value, not "delete the cell"?  You can't really "delete the cell" because it is represented by the column "Monday".  So for that row, you can clear the value out (e.g.  set to NULL or an empty string perhaps?).  If you were to "delete" it, you would be removing the entire column for all rows.

I would simply do this:

```
var b = db.AssignedExercises.Where(m =>m.Data_UserID.Equals(3)).FirstOrDefault();
b.Monday = "";   // if you want empty string, or set to DbNull
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour. You can edit the value using:

```
b.Monday = null;
```

and then call

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the value instead of using remove.  Remove, as you have discovered, deletes the row.

```
var b = db.AssignedExercises.Where(m => m.Data_UserID.Equals(3)).FirstOrDefault();
b.Monday = NULL; //or DbNull if you need to
db.SaveChanges();
```